# Passing Data from a service to a directive in AngularJs

Tags: angularjs, service, controller, directive

here my code for the directive

```
app.directive('studentlist',function(){
return{
    restrict:'E',
    scope: {},
    templateUrl:'js/directives/studentList.html'
};
```

});

and here's the code for my service

```
app.factory('students',['$http',function($http){
return $http.get('http://localhost/database2/php/students.php')
    .success(function(data){
        return data;
    })
    .error(function(err){
        return err;
    });
```

}]);

heres a snippet of my HTML

```
<div ng-repeat="student in studentList" class="row border">
        <studentList info="{{ students.info }}"></studentlist>
</div>
```

I need to know how to pass the data from the service to the directive. so it shows up in the  tag

Comment: thanks for the feedback , my json looks something like this              id : "2015552117"
FirstName : "Alexia"
MiddleName : "Gino"
LastName : "Bella"
Gender : "Male"
DateofBirth : "2015-04-30"
State : "Abuja"
YearEnrolled : "0000"
EducationalLevel : "JS 2"
lga : "Tema"
Status : ""

Answer (score 1):

```
app.directive('studentlist',function(students){
return{
    restrict:'E',
    scope: {},
    link: function(scope) {
      students.then(data) {
        console.log('putting "students" on scope!:', data);
        scope.students = data;
      };
    },
    templateUrl:'js/directives/studentList.html'
};
```

Not sure what your JSON looks like, but your directive should eventually have access to the students blob. Try putting {{students}} in the studentList directive template.

... and you don't need the binding in the directive attributes anymore.

```
<div ng-repeat="student in studentList" class="row border">
        <studentList></studentlist>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks for the feedback , however i get the array of objects but they dont show the data , Just the HTML. I used {{ student.FirstName }} in my directive based on how my json object is structure